# Pyplot Colorbar Power Issue

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am currently plotting some simulation data and I have some trouble with the powers on my color bars. They sometimes overlap with the ticks as it can be seen in the screenshot.

### [image]

For my Plot/Subplots I use:

```
    plt.figure(figsize=(5.8, 7.5))
    plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
    plt.rc('font', family='serif', size='10')
    .....
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.tight_layout()
```

How can I move the power to the right or a little bit more up?

---

Edit:

I could have provided a minimal example of the bug but I found that the problem was specific (an) older version(s) of matplotlib (1.4.3). Using 1.5.0 eliminated it completely. The power is now displayed more to the left and hence everything looks fine now. I'll not delete this question in case someone else has the same problem. Update to 1.5.0 might help!

Comment: Could you make an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Can you please post your edit as an answer so you can accept it and the SO question will be marked as answered/accepted by the system?  This is helpful so that other people skimming titles will know that you _did_ find a solution.  If that isn't a hook, then so you can get internet points ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the problem was caused by an older version of matplotlib (1.4.3). Updating to 1.5.0 solved the problem.